# How to split string by specific pattern?

Tags: c#

I have a String

```
String value ="[xasx1xx]Data1[/xasx1xx][xx22x]Data2[/xx22x][1x22aaaaax]Data3[/1x22aaaaax]";
```

I would like to split String between keywords `"[xxxxx]"` and `"[xxxxx]"` which the `[xxxxx]` is random created. So that I have output like

- data1
- data2
- data3

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Convert all the '[' into '<' and ']' into '>' and you now have an XML format. Then use the standard XML helpers in .NET.

Comment: @PhilWright how if my data contain any '[' or ']'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex [Lookaround(Zero length assertion)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get matching data as per your expectation. To get data from above data, you can use `positive lookahead` and `postive lookbehind` in following way :

```
(?<=\]).*?(?=\[)
```

`(?<=\])` :  `positive lookbehind` which looks for data after end of square bracket(])

`(?=\[)` : `positive lookahead` which looks for data before start of square bracket([)

In `C#`, you can extract matching data using above pattern with `Regex` library.

```
string input = "[xasx1xx]Data1[/xasx1xx][xx22x]Data2[/xx22x][1x22aaaaax]Data3[/1x22aaaaax]";
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\]).*?(?=\[)");
var list = matchCollection.Cast<Match>().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value))
               .Select(x=>x.Value); // list contains matching data without empty entry
```

Comment: can you please give me complete string which has above like data ?

Comment: Here is one complete sample data: `[peterChan123]It is so good!:)[/peterChan123][May_Hey] don't do this ;-] [/May_Hey][admin_Testing]!@#$%^&*()_{}:"<>?[;',./[/admin_Testing]`

Comment: what's your expected output for that?

Comment: The expected  output for that return two arrays. one will be `["peterChan123", "May_Hey", "admin_Testing"]` and the other one is `["It is so good!:)", "don't do this ;-]", "$%^&*()_{}:"<>?[;',./"]` which the second one is the hardest to do. The first one I can easily split the string by "[/" then "]" to find

Comment: You can use (?<=\]).*?((?=\])|(?=\[))  for getting your second array as per your  above output. You can  make similar regex for getting above array

Comment: `(?=\[).*?(?<=\])` for the first array?

Comment: You can use `(?<=\[)[^/;].*?(?=\])`